# How to prevent xcode opening the same file twice

Tags: xcode

Every time I double click a file it opens it in a new tab, even if the file is already open - This behaviour creates multiple tabs with the same file.
I just want it to open a new tab if the file wasn't already opened, and it was already opened then it should move to that tab.
(Like any other reasonable IDE)

Is there a way to change this annoying behaviour?
(Im using Xcode v9.3)

Comment: I **strongly** advise you switch to a great ide : AppCode.

Comment: Used it, it is good, but the lack of UI sync is a very big disadvantage for me...

Comment: I personally switch to xcode just for editing the .xib files, the rest is done outside of xcode and alt tabbing between the two IDE just for that has become a habit. Totally worth the "hassle"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is currently no workaround available.

However, tabs have a different purpose in Xcode, compared to other IDEs. Tabs in Xcode are basically separate windows of the same project, just displayed differently. This also brings some benefits. For example, you could have a tab with your storyboard and the Utilities Panel and one with only the sourcecode and every other panel closed for more space.

I personally don't really mind having no "traditional" tabs in Xcode, because you can always open files quickly with Command-Shift-O. And when I am editing multiple files at once I use the Assistant Editor with both files. But if you can't get accustomed to Xcode, there are also some alternatives like AppCode from JetBrains.